# Wifi precedence 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ssid

In my house I have a wifi router (Fritzbox) with both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, I discovered that most of my dual frequency client use always 2.4Ghz and I'm trying to understand why.
When I come home the 2.4Ghz signal is the first one reached, then my client connects to this frequency. When I'm near the access point I try to switch off and then on the wifi of my device, and the device gets the 5Ghz signal.
I have this problem with two different devices: a phone and a laptop, then I don't think it can be related to the specific device software/firmware.

How the dual SSID works? How it handles the switching of frequency?

Comment: “How the dual SSID works?” - What exactly do you mean?  There are numerous things you could mean by this.  Premium routers have a feature that will seamlessly provide a single network to both 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz clients under a single SSID

Comment: Generally, they're pretty darn lazy about it, they'll stick to one until it can no longer be seen. That makes this pretty much 'default' behaviour for dual band setups, unless the device is smart enough to realise. I don't know how you can swap priority on Windows or directly on mobile devices, but if you have a Mac synced with any iDevice over iCloud, then you can change the priority on the Mac by dragging the preferred order. That will then sync to other iDevices.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean, how the device handle a single SSID with both 2.4 and 5Ghz? As far as I saw it handles it as two separate ssid and it depends on the signal strenght. In this case, the swtiching between 2.4 and 5Ghz is almost difficult because the device once attached to 2.4 will not easily find the 5Ghz stronger than 2.4....

Comment: "how the device handles a single SSID with both 2.4 and 5Ghz?" - It doesn't.  A radio receiver that supports bands is typically used.

Answer (score 1):

### How the dual SSID work

I've set up duel band routers with separate SSIDs on each frequency before, but usually I use the same SSID for both and let the clients find which band is best.

For example instead of having one band with an SSID of `mynet2.4` and another with `mynet5` you just use `mynet` as the SSID for both (with the same passwords and such), and then the devices can pick what band they want to be on.

### How it handles the switching of frequency

The reason that your devices connect to 2.4Ghz when you get home is that the range is greater on the 2.4Ghz frequency at the same amplitude. Additionally the signal can penetrate obstructions like walls better than 5Ghz.

In theory, if both bands share a single SSID, when you get closer to your wifi access point and past obstructions, your device should be able to figure out that the 5Ghz signal strength is sufficient to warrant switching from the 2.4Ghz band to the 5Ghz band for the increased data transfer rates.  The device should be able to change bands automatically. The actuality is that sometimes this process doesn't work as expected. Someone with a bit more networking knowledge than me may be able to explain in detail, but suffice it to say it is not always perfect.

The other side of the story is that you could set up separate SSIDs and manually select which band you use. You could, for example, set your phone and laptop to only connect to the 5Ghz signal, but you won't have the range flexibility of the 2.4Ghz band unless you connect to that band manually.

### Final Words

If you do use separate SSIDs for each band and enable auto-connecting to each of those bands, your phone and laptop will connect to the first one it finds (2.4Ghz) if there is only one signal in range and will likely remain on that band until the device loses wifi. So, if this is what you are experiencing and you have different SSIDs for each band, I recommend that you try using the same SSID for both bands and see if you have better results.

Comment: @Tobia - The option does not exist.  The only thing you can do is to disable 2.4 GHz if you prefer the machine to use 5.0 Ghz.  Outside of that using two different passwords and NOT connecting to the network you don't want to use is also an option.